# OAuth login with custom API

Tags: node.js, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, backend

I have a heroku server where I host a website with Discord OAuth login to store users and their subscriptions.

I'm desigining an api to be used with other software I create in multiple platforms such as mobile app (React Native) or python software. These other softwares would only be able to be used by users in the database who own a subscription.

I'm stuck with the authentication, where a user would login through Discord and the api would return an access token to be used in the following api requests.

How can I make an app or python cli software show the Discord login page so that the user can login to make sure it's them who owns the account?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

My current understanding of how to do this is:

1. access '/api/authorize'
2. if req.user exists return user id and access token, else redirect to Discord login page with mode = 'api' in state object
3. At login redirect, if mode === 'api' return user id and access token, else do normal login

After retrieving the user id and access token, rest of api requests will be like this:

1. Get user id and access token from req.body
2. If user id exists and access token is on same row, continue with api code

Answer (score 1):

**Disregard this**

There are two approaches I've seen.

1. Open a link to authenthication flow in browser and set up an http server on localhost. This is the only way for CLI app. With the http server you can handle redirects from Discord.
2. Embed a web view in your app and let user go through OAuth flow there. You don't even need to create a http server as you can handle redirects in app.

Needless to say you would need to ship your apps with OAuth credentials, so I recommend to use other set than you use in your backend.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

If you want to verify user's identity with Discord:

1. Create an endpoint on your backend that would generate a pair of tokens, one public and one semi-private. Return both of them in response.
2. Every time a user wants to authenticate in your app, use that endpoint to retrieve tokens.
3. Open a browser or use a web view to star authentication flow. Use OAuth `state` parameter to provide your public token.
4. After the flow is completed connect a user with the pair of tokens using the one that you would get in `state` field.
5. Set another endpoint where an app would call with the semi-private token and if the flow was completed succesfuly, get whatever you use to authorize requests in your webapp (session id?). In CLI you can show a message like "Press enter when after authorization", in mobile app with a web view you can trigger it with an event from JavaScript code.

For security you should save time when a pair of tokens was generated and set a condition to complete the whole flow in let's say 10 or 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What do you mean by "ship your apps with OAuth credentials"? As in create a server for API and another one for the website? Right now I use the server to host a website where user logs in with Discord, can pay a subscription and then it shows a Dashboard so that users can control their membership.

Comment: Oh, maybe I didn't understood you correctly. I thought you wanted your apps to be usable without using the backend. Give me a few minutes :D

Comment: So you just want to give users ability to register using apps?

Comment: Basically, I provide a service in a Discord server. I created a website where users can login through Discord and pay a subscription so they can be added to the server. I now want to create other software so I want to create the api first. I only want users that have a membership to be able to use the other software I want to create. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself correctly

Comment: I don't know how or why to use the pair of tokens. I've updated my question so that you can see what I had sort of in my mind of how to do this. Thanks again!